# Is there a standard mint account for SOL?

Tags: token, spl, sol

Is there a convention to use as mint account for SOL? Similar to how ETH uses 0xeeeee.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure on how ETH uses `0xeeeee`, but on Solana each mint is NOT it's own contract. You create a mint by interacting with the [token program](https://spl.solana.com/token#example-creating-your-own-fungible-token).

Exampe in JS:

```
import { createMint } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from '@solana/web3.js';

const payer = Keypair.generate();
const mintAuthority = Keypair.generate();
const freezeAuthority = Keypair.generate();

const connection = new Connection(
  clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
  'confirmed'
);

const mint = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer,
  mintAuthority.publicKey,
  freezeAuthority.publicKey,
  9 // We are using 9 to match the CLI decimal default exactly
);

console.log(mint.toBase58());
```

Comment: Its less about a value you can use to mint sol, and more something you can use to represent sol with an account. You're right that there isn't technically a mint, but this is the reason I am looking for a convention to use for that value in a dataset

Comment: Is there any doc you can point me to, to understand how `0xeee` is used?